# The limit of time evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, time-evolution

Through reading Nenciu's rigorous proof on the Adiabatic Theorem and Gell-Mann-Low Theorem, I found:

> Since the limit $t_0\to-\infty$ does not exist for $U(t,t_0,\epsilon)$, in order to make use of the adiabatic theorem, we first compute $U_I(t,t_0,\epsilon)P$ and then limit $t_0\to-\infty$.

I am confused on why the limit of time evolution operator exists in interaction picture while not in schrodinger picture.

I guess for a Hamiltonian looks like $H=H_0+e^{-\epsilon|t|}V$, $H$ dose not vanish in the limit $t\to-\infty$ while $V_I$ does. And the differntial equations that determine time evolution operator reads respectly:
$$i\partial_tU(t,t_0)=HU(t,t_0) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ i\partial_tU_I(t,t_0)=V_I(t,t_0)$$

I am not sure about this, can anyone explain for me in details?

Moreover, I am sure I have seen many times before something like $U(0,-\infty), U(+\infty, -\infty)$ and so on. But if 'the limit $t_0\to-\infty$ does not exist for $U(t,t_0,\epsilon)$' is true as Nenciu sayed, what does they mean?

Comment: Is it about the interaction picture or the fact that they compute the limit of $UP$ instead of just $U$? Can you please give an exact reference? It is not clear, for example, which topology they refer to.

Comment: Thanks for comments. [Nenciu's proof](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:20077416) or see in (extension://bocbaocobfecmglnmeaeppambideimao/pdf/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.e-periodica.ch%2Fcntmng%3Fpid%3Dhpa-001%3A1989%3A62%3A%3A1122) \\ What I care and quate is in part 3.